# Enable Edittext after disabling it

Tags: android, android-edittext

OnButtonClick listener I want to disable the EditText to edit, and then turn it on again.

With below two lines I disabled EditText

```
 editTextWight.setEnabled(false);
 editTextWight.setFocusable(false);
```

But when I try to turn it back fails. The keyboard does not open.

```
editTextWight.setFocusable(true);
editTextWight.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editTextWight.setClickable(true);
editTextWight.setEnabled(true);
```

Please help me to enable the EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to disable edit text use

```
editTextWight.setEnabled(false);
editTextWight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
editTextWight.setFocusable(false);
```

to enable edit text use

```
editTextWight.setEnabled(true);
editTextWight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editTextWight.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this two lines that work for my project code:

```
editTextWight.setFocusable(true);
editTextWight.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

I do this for example `afterTextChanged()` is called because I had to disable this `EditText` first then enable it later!

So, just try it with ONLY two method calls above instead of all the four.

Good luck and let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Eenvincible and sajan. Your answers togheter help me to solve my problem. I enabled the editing window with these 4 methods.

```
    editTextWight.setEnabled(true);
    editTextWight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editTextWight.setFocusable(true);
    editTextWight.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```